# How do you mount an NFS Share in Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, nfs, truenas

I have FreeNAS exposing an NFS. How do I access this from Windows 7? I have enabled the "Services for NFS" within Windows Features.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Map a drive as normal, only instead of `\\server\share` format you use `server:/share` format (don't forget the colon).

[Here's a nice post](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=310168) from the Ubuntu forums, but should be the same for NFS served by others.

Comment: I tried this a million times. I figured there had to be some other way to do it. It turns out, you need to restart after enabling the NFS Services, thanks!

Comment: D'oh!  Stinkin' Windows :)

Comment: Now it isn't working again, by default it mapped it to Z, I unmapped it to map to another drive. Now I get "An unexpected error"

Comment: If I restart I can mount again, it looks like they still have some kinks to work out. It seems like I also can't pass authentication information over.

Comment: Another strange bit with this is if you map a drive from windows explorer you get a different dialog from the one on the context menu of the computer start menu item